# Excel: re-structure multiple columns to two columns (for pivot tables)

Tags: excel, data-structures, pivot

My data is like this:

```
  Col1  |    Col2
   1    |    a,b,c
   2    |    d,e
   3    |    f
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
  Col1  |   Col2
   1    |   a
   1    |   b
   1    |   c
   2    |   d
   2    |   e
   3    |   f
```

I've tried experimenting with offset and just general transpose, but haven't been able to figure out a way to do this. I have 1,000 rows (which in the finished product will be several thousand), so manually is not an option.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Take a look at Text to Columns, using a comma delimiter. It's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Or, assuming that data is in A1:B3, enter this **array formula**** in e.g. D1:

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(0+(ROW($A$1:$A$3)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$1:$A$3))),1+LEN($B$1:$B$3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1:$B$3,",","")))>=ROWS($1:1),0)),"")

Copy down until you start to get blanks for the results.

Then, in E1, this (non-array) formula:

=IF(D1="","",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$3,0)),",",REPT(" ",41)),41*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,D1)-1)+1,41)))

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*